beforeSave is not firing when saving entity
im trying to use Cakephp version 3.10 to fire a beforeSave event but it's not doing anything.
This is the only Controller / Table that dont wa
Controller
public function edit($id = null)
{
    $company = $this->Companies->get($id, [
        'contain' => [],
    ]);
    if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {
        $company = $this->Companies->patchEntity($company, $this->request->getData());
        if ($this->Companies->save($company)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The company has been saved.'));

            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('The company could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
    }
    $users = $this->Companies->Users->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $this->set(compact('company', 'users'));
}

Table:
<?php
namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Query;
use Cake\ORM\RulesChecker;
use Cake\ORM\Table;
use Cake\Validation\Validator;

/**
 * Companies Model
 *
 * @property \App\Model\Table\UsersTable&\Cake\ORM\Association\BelongsTo $Users
 * @property \App\Model\Table\OcaServicesTable&\Cake\ORM\Association\BelongsTo $OcaServices
 *
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\Company get($primaryKey, $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\Company newEntity($data = null, array $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\Company[] newEntities(array $data, array $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\Company|false save(\Cake\Datasource\EntityInterface $entity, $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\Company saveOrFail(\Cake\Datasource\EntityInterface $entity, $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\Company patchEntity(\Cake\Datasource\EntityInterface $entity, array $data, array $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\Company[] patchEntities($entities, array $data, array $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\Company findOrCreate($search, callable $callback = null, $options = [])
 *
 * @mixin \Cake\ORM\Behavior\TimestampBehavior
 */
class CompaniesTable extends Table
{
    /**
     * Initialize method
     *
     * @param array $config The configuration for the Table.
     * @return void
     */
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setTable('companies');
        $this->setDisplayField('name');
        $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

        // $this->addBehavior('Common');
        // $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

        $this->belongsTo('Users', [
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Default validation rules.
     *
     * @param \Cake\Validation\Validator $validator Validator instance.
     * @return \Cake\Validation\Validator
     */
    public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
    {
        $validator
            ->integer('id')
            ->allowEmptyString('id', null, 'create');

        $validator
            ->scalar('name')
            ->maxLength('name', 255)
            ->allowEmptyString('name');

        $validator
            ->scalar('oca_url')
            ->maxLength('oca_url', 255)
            ->allowEmptyString('oca_url');

        $validator
            ->scalar('oca_user')
            ->maxLength('oca_user', 255)
            ->allowEmptyString('oca_user');

        $validator
            ->scalar('oca_password')
            ->maxLength('oca_password', 255)
            ->allowEmptyString('oca_password');

        return $validator;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a rules checker object that will be used for validating
     * application integrity.
     *
     * @param \Cake\ORM\RulesChecker $rules The rules object to be modified.
     * @return \Cake\ORM\RulesChecker
     */
    public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules)
    {
        return $rules;
    }

    public function beforeSave($event, $entity, $options) {
        \Cake\Log\Log::debug('CommonBehavior loaded');
        debug($event);
    }

}

The beforeSave is not firing, only with this Table / Controller, other controllers works well.
I followed the guide here: https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/behaviors.html
Cakephp version: 3.10
PHP Version: 7.4
What im doing wrong ?
Thanks

I've tried just your beforeSave() on my local setup and it works. You said "...but it's not doing anything",  so even your controller isn't working? Is your patchEntity() writing the data and giving the success message?

In your controller, debug(get_class($this->Companies)); just to make sure that it's using the CompaniesTable class that you think it is.
